# Blazor WASM CCS position deployed vs local

Tags: deployment, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have this Blazor WASM SPA that, when deployed, lives in a folder called SPA. When I develop I do not have this extra level and that makes it cumbersome since certain elemenets need to be referenced "directly" when deployed.

An example:

Deployed: CSS background - image: url('/SPA/css/bg2.JPG');
Local: CSS background - image: url('/css/bg2.JPG');

I could introduce a SPA level in my wwwroot folder but that would give me other problems.

Any ideas?

Kind regards

Comment: app base path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-base-path-1

Comment: Thanks Brian but I already tried that. For example in one of my pages I have 

<link href="css/xyz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
Which works fine with base path /SPA/ but further down with inline CSS I have to specifically specify SPA: like <img style="src='/SPA/css/tickmark.png'" />